# why the following notice is generating in textarea?

Tags: php, html

Why the following notice is generating in the text area ? After running the php file on local machine.

here is the notice with screenshot:
               [image: schema]

notice in the image:

> **Notice**:  Undefined variable: user_input in **C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\index.php** on line **15**

here is my code, which I am writting in netbeans:

```
<?php
   $find= array('alex','billy','dale');
   $replace=array('a**x','b***y','d**e');
   if(isset($_POST['user_input'])&&!empty($_POST['user_input'])){
      $user_input = $_POST['user_input'];
      $user_input_new= str_ireplace($find, $replace, $user_input);
      echo $user_input_new;
   }
?>
<hr>
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
   <textarea name="user_input" rows="6" cols="30">
     <?php
       echo $user_input;
     ?>
  </textarea><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting the notice because `$user_input;` is not defined since the `POST['user_input']` is not set. To avoid the notice print the `$user_input;` only if has been defined

```
echo isset($user_input) ? $user_input : '';
```

Since you are printing `$user_input` inside the `textarea` so the error is printed there

Comment: In PHP7 you could also use the [null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op): `echo $user_input ?? '';`

Comment: Yeah that's correct but I don't know what version OP is using so i prefer to use this way

Comment: Agreed your way is the safer option for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<?php
$find = array('alex', 'billy', 'dale');
$replace = array('a**x', 'b***y', 'd**e');
if (isset($_POST['user_input']) && !empty($_POST['user_input'])) {
    $user_input = $_POST['user_input'];
    $user_input_new = str_ireplace($find, $replace, $user_input);
    echo $user_input_new;
}
?>
<hr>

<form action="index.php" method="POST">
    <textarea name="user_input" rows="6" cols="30">
        <?php
        if (isset($user_input)) {
            echo $user_input;
        }
        ?>
    </textarea><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put `isset()` condition over `$user_input` before using it in textarea:

```
<textarea name="user_input" rows="6" cols="30">
      <?php
      if(isset($user_input)){
        echo $user_input;
      }
      ?>
</textarea><br><br>
```

OR You can do some like this

```
<textarea name="user_input" rows="6" cols="30">
      <?=isset($user_input) ? $user_input : "" ?>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set `$user_input` before the if statement

```
$find= array('alex','billy','dale');
$replace=array('a**x','b***y','d**e');
$user_input = '';
if(isset($_POST['user_input'])&&!empty($_POST['user_input'])){
    $user_input = $_POST['user_input'];
    $user_input_new= str_ireplace($find, $replace, $user_input);
    echo $user_input_new;
}

// ...
```

Comment: Also correct! but better to use isset condition rather than initializing with empty string.

Comment: @Maha Dev Fair enough... but I think that initializing variables is not a bad badi idea at all ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is because the $_POST value isn't set. It can't be if the form never had been submited.
Change your condition to:

```
# checks if the form as been submitted, with the submit input's name
if (isset($_POST['submit']) {
    $user_input = $_POST['user_input'];
} else {
    # If not, it will write nothing
    $user_input = "";
}
```

Or do it directly in the form with a [ternary operator](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwio0ffsgKHSAhUEUBQKHXKxDKwQFgg1MAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sitepoint.com%2Fusing-the-ternary-operator%2F&usg=AFQjCNF5STAvP_3OV0kPE8uR6y8I7nCBfA&sig2=oTfRGaIt8r2cyXoatNh-bw):

```
<textarea name="user_input" rows="6" cols="30">
  <?php
     echo isset($_POST['submit']) ? $_POST['user_input'] : "";
  ?>
</textarea><br><br>
```

**EDIT by *Pankaj Makwana* (corrected):**
Or *Pankaj Makwana*'s edit of my answer (which isn't about **ternary operator** but [short open tags](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)).

```
<textarea name="user_input" rows="6" cols="30">
   <?=isset($_POST['user_input']) ? $_POST['user_input'] : "" ?>
</textarea>
```

**EDIT: PHP7's [null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/fr/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)** way:
Using *Pankaj Makwana*'s edit of my answer.

```
<textarea name="user_input" rows="6" cols="30">
   <?=$_POST['user_input'] ?? "" ?>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `$user_input` does not have value in it. In this case use `isset()` to check if a variable exist.

```
isset($user_input)
{
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable will fill with data whenever your POST action happens so you have to check it to not be empty or it is isset or not!

```
if (isset($user_input) & !empty($user_input)) {
    echo $user_input;
}
```